# Can't reconnect VPS Essential OVH after removing set_hostname from cloud-init

Tags: ubuntu, vps, disaster-recovery, cloud-init, ovh

I have a VPS Essential in OVH with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed.

I just removed the `set_hostname` module of the `cloud_init_modules` from `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` and reboot the system and now I cannot connect to it, this is the line I removed but from other of my servers: ([image: this is the line I removed but from other of my servers]).

I tried to connect through SSH but is trowing timeouts and through the OVH manager panel with KVM and rescue reboot but seems is not working. When I tried to connect to he KVM but it tells me this: [image: it tells me this] in the other hand, If I try to reboot the system this happens: [image: this happens].

I have a production env running on the server with a database that I cannot lost. It is possible to recover the system? or at least recover the hard disk data?

Comment: You should first contact OVH support.

Comment: For sure I did, but I wanted to know if at least is possible to recover from this situation

Comment: What did they tell you?

Comment: I'm still waiting for a response, btw it is possible to lost the connection of a VPS because of this?

Comment: Now I manage to get into Recovery mode through KVM, but when I reboot the system and I select the normal system to boot, it returns again to the recovery mode, do you know what is happening?